# Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox: very bad performance with VMSVGA

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, performance

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox version 6.0.14 (macOS host). It works perfectly well with the VBoxVGA graphics controller and 3D acceleration enabled.

If I change the graphics controller to VMSVGA then performance becomes very bad. It significantly affects usability. If I change it to VBoxSVGA, it becomes literally unusably slow.

VirtualBox 6.1 has dropped support for VBoxVGA (VMSVGA is the recommended choice for Linux guests). If I upgrade VirtualBox to 6.1 I will not be able to use VBoxVGA anymore.  Is there a way to make this version of Ubuntu run with reasonable performance with the VMSVGA graphics controller?

---

In VirtualBox 6.1.10, the performance with VMSVGA is still so bad as to make the system unusable.

Comment: Same issue here but with VBoxSVGA without 3D acceleration. It worked fine for 2 months, then suddenly there's like 1 frame per 5 sec updated... When I change to VMSVGA, upon boot I get error: "Failed to register resizing support rc=VERR_RESOURCE_BUSY"

Comment: @warchantua I have no solution for you. I still use VBox 6.0.x for this reason, and will continue doing so for as long as I need Ubuntu 16.04. However, Ubuntu 20.04 works reasonably well for me with VMSVGA. Not nearly as well as 16.04 does with VBoxVGA, but it's definitely usable.